# Navbar stuttering/disappearing when sticky is enabled

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, sticky

I am having a problem with my sticky navbar. After scrolling past the header/100vh I want the navbar to be sticky and not stutter.

I have got it be sticky after the header/100vh using jQuery but when you see on jsfiddle it removes the div above the about section and makes it sticky which causes the stutter.

I want the div to stay so it wont cause the issue and will be smoother.

Thanks

View on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2v18er30/24/

```
<body>
<section id="home" class="hero hero-gradient is-primary is-fullheight">
    <div class="hero-head m-t-md">
        <header class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="img/logo/logo-white-50x50.png" alt="logo">
                         </a>
                    <span class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbarMenuHeroC">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div id="navbarMenuHeroC" class="navbar-menu">
                    <div class="navbar-end">
                        <span class="navbar-item">
                          <a href="#home" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold is-hidden-desktop">
                            HOME
                          </a>
                          <a href="#about" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold is-hidden-desktop">
                            ABOUT
                          </a>
                          <a href="#skills" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold is-hidden-desktop">
                            SKILLS
                          </a>
                          <a href="#work" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold is-hidden-desktop">
                            WORK
                          </a>
                          <a href="#" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold is-hidden-desktop">
                            BLOG
                          </a>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container has-text-centered is-family-secondary-serif">
            <img src="img/avatars/avatar-placeholder2.png" alt="illustration of me">
            <h1 class="title is-3 is-uppercase m-t-lg has-text-weight-normal">
                Lorem Ipsum
            </h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-size--2 is-uppercase has-text-weight-bold">
                Lorem Ipsum
            </h2>
            <div class="icon_animate">
            <a href="#about" class="is-size-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i>
             </a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<nav>
<header class="navbar is-hidden-mobile is-hidden-tablet-only">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#home">
                <img class="m-t-sm" src="img/logo/logo-color-50x50.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarMenuHeroC navScroll" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-end">
                <a href="#home" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold m-r-lg">
                    HOME
                </a>
                <a href="#about" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold m-r-lg">
                    ABOUT
                </a>
                <a href="#skills" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold m-r-lg">
                    SKILLS
                </a>
                <a href="#work" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold m-r-lg">
                    WORK
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-item uppercase has-text-weight-bold">
                    BLOG
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</nav>
<section id="about" class="section has-background-white-ter">
    <div class="container has-text-left">
        <div class="columns is-vcentered">
            <div class="column is-7">
               <div class="content p-r-xxl">
                    <h2 class="title is-2 has-text-weight-bold is-family-secondary-serif">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    <p>MLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.
                        <br>
                        <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                        <br>
                        <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetti
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-6">
                <figure class="image is-4by3">
                    <img src="img/avatars/ds1-about.png" alt="photo of myself">
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Skills -->
<section id="skills" class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-mobile">
                <h2 class="title has-text-centered m-t-xl m-b-xl has-text-weight-bold is-family-secondary-serif is-size-1">Skills</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-one-third is-mobile m-b-xxl">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler is-horizontal-center is-size--2 is-primary m-b-lg"></i>
                <h3 class="subtitle has-text-centered has-text-weight-bold">UI/UX Design</h3>
                <p class="has-text-centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-one-third is-mobile m-b-xl">
                <i class="fas fa-paint-brush is-horizontal-center is-size--2 is-primary m-b-lg"></i>
                <h3 class="subtitle has-text-centered has-text-weight-bold">Web Design</h3>
                <p class="has-text-centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-one-third is-mobile m-b-xl">
                <i class="fas fa-code is-horizontal-center is-size--2 is-primary m-b-lg"></i>
                <h3 class="subtitle has-text-centered has-text-weight-bold">Front-End Development</h3>
                <p class="has-text-centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set `position: sticky`, which would solve the "stuttering" or you create a placeholder for your navbar when it's sticky I've provided an example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // Even when the window is resized, run this code.
  $(window).resize(function(){
    
    // Variables
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    
    // Find the value of 90% of the viewport height
    var onehundredpercent = 1 * windowHeight;
    
    // When the document is scrolled ninety percent, toggle the classes
    // Does not work in iOS 7 or below
    // Hasn't been tested in iOS 8
    $(document).scroll(function(){
      
      // Store the document scroll function in a variable
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      
      // If the document is scrolled 90%
      if( y > onehundredpercent) {
        
        // Add placeholder
        if (!$('nav').hasClass('sticky')) {
         $('nav').after('<div class="placeholder" style="height:' +  $('nav').outerHeight() + 'px"></div>')
        }
        // Add the "sticky" class
        $('nav').addClass('sticky');
      } else {
        // Else remove it.
        $('nav').next('.placeholder').remove();
        $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
      }
      
    });

  // Call it on resize.
  }).resize();
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

section {
  background: green;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  Hello World
</header>
<nav>
  I'm a navbar
</nav>
<section>I'm a section</section>
<section>I'm a section</section>
<section>I'm a section</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked. It was the placeholder in which I wanted to do.